# How to set specific Smart Card reader as default, when having multiple readers on computer

Tags: windows, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I have a laptop with an integrated Smart Card reader (Broadcom). Applications I use insist on using specific Smart Card readers (USB tokens). Therefore I must insert that second SC reader in my system and I can't remove the first one.

The problem lies in a fact that those applications use only the default (first found) SD reader they find to query for Smart Card. And thus always report my SD reader as "empty".

I need to force them to read my "second reader" as it is my primary.

The question is: Is it possible to somehow select default card reader without disabling the other one? Is it possible to have Windows asking for which card reader to use?

Answer (score 2):

I have Windows 10 1809 and I have noticed that the name of the default reader is dependent on which registry keys is alphabetically first under

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\Readers

I added a space to the beginning of the key to the one I wanted to be listed first and this caused it to sort alphabetically first and become the default.

Answer (score 0):

I've devised "a hacky" solution that worked for me, but I'm sure that is not really the proper one. I've changed `Groups` field from `SCard$DefaultReaders` to `_dummy_SCard$DefaultReaders`, in this registry location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\Readers\Broadcom Corp Contacted SmartCard 0
```

I've essentially disabled my Broadcom smartcard reader. This is working for Windows 10 64-bit and registry location is probably quite similar on 32-bit systems.

> Note: Great utility that helped me was `certutil -scinfo -v` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my knowledge there is no clean centralized solution. The idea behind the PCSC architecture was, if several readers are connected, that you choose the one you want to connect to by identifiying the card you want to address. For the use case "more than one reader present, but application always wants a specific one, even without knowing something concerning the card" the application has to take care by itself. (Most achieve this by remembering, which one was chosen the last time.)